# Treeview structure without heavy plugins

Tags: javascript, html, css, treeview

I would like to display my list of bookmarks on my personal page.

Since it is huge and well organized in folders, I would like to have a tree view where the user can (un)fold folders like with a file browser (like the bookmark manager in many browsers).

I found http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/, https://github.com/chenglou/react-treeview, https://github.com/pqx/react-ui-tree and https://github.com/alexcurtis/react-treebeard, but I would prefer something very light (I can code it myself) that doesn't require to install jQuery or React (I just want to display a tree, no drag'n'drop or advanced features, just expanding, and navigation with the arrows.

I also found https://github.com/resnyanskiy/js.tree and https://github.com/justinchmura/js-treeview, but they don't support arrows navigation.

Maybe can I get the treeview code of the chromium bookmarks manager ?

Do you know any library or can you explain me the simplest way to program it ?

Comment: what you have tried so far? code?

Comment: I tried to read the codes of those programs, since I never learned JS (although I can code) or its browser interaction.

Comment: js and jQuery are awesome just learn some syntax and you have so many controls over the html, Try learning it, it will help a lot and speedup your development time. Have fun codding

Comment: Yeah, js is really simple, I know how to code (like I can solve algorithmic challenges using node), but I'm really not interested in web development. Thanks you a lot for this css trick !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the css only solution

Have a look at this:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block }

body { line-height: 1 }

ol, ul { list-style: none }

blockquote, q { quotes: none }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

body {
  font: 100% "roboto", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  background-color:#eee;
}

a { text-decoration: none; }

/**
 * Hidden fallback
 */


/**
 * Styling navigation
 */

header {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 22.5rem;
  margin-top:150px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

/**
 * Styling top level items
 */

.nav a, .nav label {
  display: block;
 padding: .85rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #151515;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #1d1d1d;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in;
  transition: all .25s ease-in;
}

.nav a:focus, .nav a:hover, .nav label:focus, .nav label:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background: #030303;
}

.nav label { cursor: pointer; }

/**
 * Styling first level lists items
 */

.group-list a, .group-list label {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  background: #252525;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #373737;
}

.group-list a:focus, .group-list a:hover, .group-list label:focus, .group-list label:hover { background: #131313; }

/**
 * Styling second level list items
 */

.sub-group-list a, .sub-group-list label {
  padding-left: 4rem;
  background: #353535;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #474747;
}

.sub-group-list a:focus, .sub-group-list a:hover, .sub-group-list label:focus, .sub-group-list label:hover { background: #232323; }

/**
 * Styling third level list items
 */

.sub-sub-group-list a, .sub-sub-group-list label {
  padding-left: 6rem;
  background: #454545;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #575757;
}

.sub-sub-group-list a:focus, .sub-sub-group-list a:hover, .sub-sub-group-list label:focus, .sub-sub-group-list label:hover { background: #333333; }

/**
 * Hide nested lists
 */

.group-list, .sub-group-list, .sub-sub-group-list {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__list input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + ul { /* reset the height when checkbox is checked */
max-height: 1000px; }

/**
 * Rotating chevron icon
 */

label > span {
  float: right;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .65s ease;
  transition: transform .65s ease;
}

.nav__list input[type=checkbox]:checked + label > span {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div >
<header role="banner">
  <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav__list">
      <li>
        <input id="group-1" type="checkbox" hidden />
        <label for="group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> First level</label>
        <ul class="group-list">
          <li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
          <li>
            <input id="sub-group-1" type="checkbox" hidden />
            <label for="sub-group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Second level</label>
            <ul class="sub-group-list">
              <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
              <li>
                <input id="sub-sub-group-1" type="checkbox" hidden />
                <label for="sub-sub-group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Third level</label>
                <ul class="sub-sub-group-list">
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
      <input id="group-2" type="checkbox" hidden />
      <label for="group-2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> First level</label>
      <ul class="group-list">
        <li>
        <li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
        <input id="sub-group-2" type="checkbox" hidden />
        <label for="sub-group-2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Second level</label>
        <ul class="sub-group-list">
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li>
            <input id="sub-sub-group-2" type="checkbox" hidden />
            <label for="sub-sub-group-2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Third level</label>
            <ul class="sub-sub-group-list">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
      <input id="group-3" type="checkbox" hidden />
      <label for="group-3"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> First level</label>
      <ul class="group-list">
        <li>
        <li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
        <input id="sub-group-3" type="checkbox" hidden />
        <label for="sub-group-3"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Second level</label>
        <ul class="sub-group-list">
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li>
            <input id="sub-sub-group-3" type="checkbox" hidden />
            <label for="sub-sub-group-3"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Third level</label>
            <ul class="sub-sub-group-list">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
      <input id="group-4" type="checkbox" hidden />
      <label for="group-4"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> First level</label>
      <ul class="group-list">
        <li>
        <li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
        <input id="sub-group-4" type="checkbox" hidden />
        <label for="sub-group-4"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Second level</label>
        <ul class="sub-group-list">
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Source:  http://www.cssscript.com/multilevel-accordion-menu-with-plain-html-css/

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I don't think it looks like the examples I provided.

Comment: you can modify it as you want it is just plain css

Comment: Yes, but I want to have something interactive :)

Comment: Ok let me try as your way

Comment: Please see now @Labo

Comment: WOW AMAZING !!!!!!!!
It's really beautiful !!!
Since I am a codegolf and optimisation maniac, I'll make a js script that transforms json to html, but the key is really CSS. I should REALLY learn more about CSS.

Comment: I forgot I wanted to control it with the keyboard :(
Do you think it is possible to use JS to get the keyevents to move between and activate the hidden checkboxes ?